# Problems with selecting files with FileReader in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

Im trying to make a video preview script. I want one function for both drag and drop and files selected by an input type="file" element. Here is the function:

```
                function FileHandler(files){
                    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

                        file = files[i];

                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function(evt){
                            var VideoSpan = document.createElement('span');
                            var Video = document.createElement('video');
                            VideoSpan.classList.add('VideoPreviewSpaner');
                            Video.classList.add('VideoPreview');
                            Video.controls="controls";
                            Video.src = evt.target.result
                            VideoSpan.appendChild(Video);
                            document.getElementById('VideoWindow').appendChild(VideoSpan);
                            document.getElementById('VideoWindow').style.display = "block";
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }
                }
```

And then the

```
<input type="file" id="OpenFileDialog" multiple onchange="FileHandler(this.files)">
```

And the dnd handler:

```
            function d(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                files = e.dataTransfer.files;
                FileHandler(files);
            }
            document.getElementById('droparea').addEventListener('drop',d,false);
```

I really can't see whats wrong the reader.onload is never called! It would be great with some help!

Answer (score 2):

Got here when I faced similar issue.

Try to implement **onerror** and you will find Google Chrome throwing a "Security error". The same works in Firefox(7.0.1) though.

Its due to the local file security restriction Google Chrome has imposed upon the developers. This local files security restriction really takes a toll on quick dev-testings!

Put the HTML on a web-server, the issue is resolved. No web-server? try on Firefox!
***--allow-file-access-from-files*** option never really worked for me!

Best,
Sridhar